# Excel 2016 VBA - Slow performance

Tags: vba, excel

Our company recently upgraded to Office 2016 and a lot of people in the office are experiencing very slow calculation speeds (like 1%/s if their lucky).

I have tried restarting, repairing Office, removing the add-ins, etc. I narrowed it down to a file having VBA in it. For example, I created two files: both have two columns of 10k observations of hard-coded numbers and one calculated column. The only difference is that file #1 uses a predefined formula (below) while file #2 uses a UDF (below) and is saved as .xlsm instead of .xlsx.

File #1 (.xlsx)

```
C1 = 100 * A1 + B1
```

File #2 (.xlsm)

```
C1 = UDF(A1, B1)
```

Where UDF is defined as:

```
Function UDF(x, y)
  UDF = 100 * x + y
End Function
```

Are there any steps I can try to fix this issue? Not everyone is experiencing it either. I've sent the VBA file around and for those that it calculates fast (i.e. instantaneously) I had them screenshot their VBA references but they are the same as what I have.

Comment: I'd start by checking what add-ins are installed.

Comment: That's one of the things I checked - and I put that in the question

Comment: Well pardon me. Did you start Excel in safe mode?

Comment: Yes, and it calculates normal (i.e. instantaneously)

Comment: Then the issue is an add-in or other startup file.

Comment: The only add-in I can't disable is 'think-cell' but other than that I have disabled all.

Comment: But everyone in my office has that add-in and some people aren't experiencing this issue. So if it's a start up file, how do I isolate it?

Comment: First make sure you disabled all COM add-ins as well as regular Excel ones. Then check XLSTART folders (there are 2, plus any user designated startup ones). Then see if there's an `.xlb` file on the computer and move/rename it temporarily to see if that helps. Last, check printer drivers.

Comment: I was able to disable that think-cell add-in and now everything is fine. I wonder if the others have a different version such that this isn't an issue for them. Regardless, that solved my problem so if you move your comment to an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If starting Excel in Safe Mode cures the problem, it has to be down to an add-in or startup file - or some combination of them. Disable them all and see if that fixes it, then you can re-enable one by one to try and narrow down the culprit.